# Solve the recurrence as the figure below

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNwux.png)
To prove $T(n) = \Theta(n^2)$ , it is necessary to simultaneously prove  $T(n) = O(n^2)$ and $T(n) = \Omega(n^2)$ .

But I don't have any clue about proving $T(n) = \Omega(n^2)$, could you help me? Or there may be any other methods?

I have proved $T(n) = O(n^2)$ using Mathematical induction.

Comment: this is a question best suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Actually I post it on Mathematics Stack Exchange,  I don't konw why it be shown here.

Comment: What is the recurrence relation that T(n) satisfies? The one in the image is an inequality satisfied by (for example) T(n)=0.

Comment: If you replace <= with = in the image, it's easy to see that T(n) >= T(n-1) + c2n for n>1, which almost immediately gives you that T(n) = Omega(n^2).

Comment: This is a question assigned by my teacher, perhaps he made a mistake, here should be the equation.